# How do I increase the width of the content column in Quarto

Tags: css, containers, quarto

I have a quarto html page with a sidebar and a table-of-contents (i.e. a 3 column page). I would like to increase the default-width of the content column (the central column) which is now fixed at ~950px. How do I do that?

**quarto.yml**

```
project:
  type: website

website:
  title: "Big Center Section"
  sidebar:
    style: "docked"
    search: false
    contents:
      - section: "Sidebar"
        contents:
          - text: "Item 1"
            url:  ./somewhere.html

format:
  html:
    theme:
      - flatly
      - custom.scss
    css: styles.css
    toc: true
```

jupyter ipynb page

```
---
title: "Big wide middle section"
jupyter: python3
format:
    html:
        code-fold: true
        code-line-numbers: true
---


Second cell:

# SOME REALLY REALLY REALLY LONG HEADING I WANT 2000px WIDE.....
```

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Answer (score 9):

### Update

**Quarto version 1.3** allows setting the width of the sidebar, the body of the document, the margin of the document, and the margins between these elements (gutters) with `sidebar-width`, `body-width`, `margin-width`, and `gutter-width` options.

`sidebar-width`, `body-width`, and `margin-width` should be specified in pixels (px) and `gutter-width` may be specified in pixels or other units such as em or rem. It is also possible to use SCSS variables. Read [Article Grid Customization](https://quarto.org/docs/prerelease/1.3/grid.html#background) from quarto docs for details.

**_quarto.yml**

```
project:
    type: website
  
website:
  title: "Big Center Section"
  sidebar:
    style: "docked"
    search: false
    contents:
      - section: "Sidebar"
        contents:
          - index.qmd

format:
  html:
    grid: 
      body-width: 2000px
      sidebar-width: 200px
      margin-width: 200px
    toc: true
```

---

### Old Answer

We can increase the width of content column by setting `width` to 2000px of `#quarto-document-content` (and also changing the margins for right sidebar to push it to the right)

---

**_quarto.yml**

```
project:
    type: website
  
website:
  title: "Big Center Section"
  sidebar:
    style: "docked"
    search: false
    contents:
      - section: "Sidebar"
        contents:
          - index.qmd

format:
  html:
    toc: true
    css: styles.css
```

---

**index.qmd**

```
---
title: "Big wide middle section"
jupyter: python3
format:
    html:
      code-fold: true
      code-line-numbers: true
---


# SOME REALLY REALLY REALLY LONG HEADING I WANT 2000px WIDE.....

# SOME REALLY REALLY REALLY LONG HEADING I WANT 2000px WIDE.....

# SOME REALLY REALLY REALLY LONG HEADING I WANT 2000px WIDE.....
```

---

**styles.css**

```
/* css styles */

#quarto-document-content {
  width: 2000px;
}

#quarto-margin-sidebar {
  margin-right: -600px;
  margin-left: 500px;
}
```

---

[image: with a content column of width 2000px]

---

(Note that,  I have zoomed out to take this screenshot of the website page)

Comment: SUPER DUPER HELPFUL. Thank you.

Comment: The problem with this proposed solution is that it doesn't work if you have notes/citations/references in the margin.

This workaround only works if you have no margin content.

Comment: yes may be. Can you post a question with reproducible example for this problem so that I can look into this?! @gradcylinder

Comment: @ shafee
I'm going to skip adding a reprex; just use the example you used to add `reference-location: margin` to the format section.

Then put something in the margin and render your page.