# Increase width of the content column in Quarto html doc when including sidebar & margin contents

Tags: html, quarto

There are a number of similar questions already, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75049013/how-to-make-a-quarto-html-document-use-the-full-screen-width) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73611184/how-do-i-increase-the-width-of-the-content-column-in-quarto). But I haven't found an answer for how to increase the width of the content column when the document also includes sidebar and margin content. The [Quarto documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/page-layout.html) says to use `body-width` in the yaml, but that doesn't seem do anything.

Here's a simple quarto document:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format:
  html: 
    grid:
      sidebar-width: 200px
      body-width: 2000px
      margin-width: 400px
      gutter-width: 1.5rem
    toc: true
    toc-location: left
editor: visual
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.

## Running Code

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that includes both content and the output of embedded code. You can embed code like this:

```{r}
1 + 1
```

::: {.column-margin}
This is my margin content
:::

You can add options to executable code like this

```{r}
#| echo: false
2 * 2
```

The `echo: false` option disables the printing of code (only output is displayed).
````

But the output is still quite narrow:
[image]

Is there any way to make the content fill up the available space in the browser window?

Comment: Are you using quarto version 1.3?

Comment: I was still on 1.2. Installing version 1.3 fixed it.